# How to retrieve data objects in firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just started using Firestore as the app I'm creating has a survey area which will filter products according to the chosen criteria. I'm trying figure out how to get data from the database that is stored as an object. (please refer to the 'action' data). I have included an image of my database layout below.

This is the loop I'm using to retrieve all the data in the store:

```
var allProds = [Product]()

for document in snapshot.documents {
    let product = Product()
    let productData = document.data()

    product.brandName = productData["brand"] as? String ?? ""
    product.productName = productData["name"] as? String ?? ""
    product.raters = productData["totalraters"] as? Int ?? 0
    product.totalRating = productData["totalrating"] as? Int ?? 0
    product.smallImage = productData["urlsmall"] as? String ?? ""
    product.action = productData["action"]

    allProds += [product]

}

return allProds
```

How do I get the actions data? And is there a way to transform this into a String of just the values?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let actions = productData["action"] as? [String:Bool]
{
   print(actions["Nourishing"])
   let str = actions.keys.joined(separator:",")
   print(str)
}
```

Comment: Great, it took me a while to figure this out but got there before seeing this unfortunately! Would you know if I can turn it into a string of just the keys? like: "Nourishing, Radiance"